# Create auto increment key-value with pyspark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have `rdd` with list like:

```
['a','b','c']
```

How to create new `rdd` with key value like:

```
{0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c'}
```

Comment: All what you want is just to obtain `{0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c'}` from that list?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is of very low quality and presents no effort at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy:

```
>>> data = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> distData = sc.parallelize(data)
>>> distData.collect()
['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> distData = distData.zipWithIndex()
>>> distData.collect()
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]

>>> distData = distData.map(lambda (x, y): (y,x))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

The need to map to swap the key-value if you want the index as the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate it with a for loop.

```
lis = ['a','b','c']
dic = {}
for x in range(len(lis)):
   dic[x] = lis[x]

print dic
```

In this code we are appending each item in the list to dictionary with the index value of the list as the key value.
**Output:**

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

Comment: Thank you but i want to do with pyspark.